# how to dsiplay user profile with all user info when login to website in php pdo mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I created two tables in mysql phhmyadmin. 1)reg_users 2)cam_details
  reg_users table takes the email and pass which some unique id also.
  cam_details table takes the camera related info also have an user_id which is unique. 
  But the problem is when user logged into the site I want to display the cam_details info which the user previously uploaded.
But I can't able to do this.
I'm new to php. Is there any way to display cam_info after logged into the website?

I have also used sessions.

[image]

[image]

This is class.user.php file-

```
<?php

require_once 'dbconfig.php';

class USER
{   
    private $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }


    public function runQuery($sql)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function lasdID()
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->lastInsertId();
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function register($email,$upass,$code)
    {
        try
        {                           
            $password = md5($upass);
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO reg_users(userEmail,userPass,tokenCode) 
                                                         VALUES(:user_mail, :user_pass, :active_code)");
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_mail",$email);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_pass",$password);
            $stmt->bindparam(":active_code",$code);
            $stmt->execute();   
            return $stmt;
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function login($email,$upass)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM reg_users WHERE userEmail=:email_id");
            $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
            {
                if($userRow['userStatus']=="Y")
                {
                    if($userRow['userPass']==md5($upass))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['userID'];
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        header("Location: index.php?error");
                        exit;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    header("Location: index.php?inactive");
                    exit;
                }   
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: index.php?error");
                exit;
            }       
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }


    public function is_logged_in()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['userSession']))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function redirect($url)
    {
        header("Location: $url");
    }

    public function view_item($id){

    try{


        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT user_id, user_name, mobile, cam_name, rent, model, cam_img, upd_date FROM cam_details WHERE user_id = :id');
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;   

    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function final_view()
    {
    try
    {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT user_id, user_name, mobile, cam_name, rent, model, cam_img, upd_date FROM cam_details WHERE user_id= :id');
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
    public function getDetails()
    {

    try
    {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT user_id, user_name, mobile, cam_name, rent, model, cam_img, upd_date FROM cam_details ORDER BY user_id DESC');
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        session_destroy();
        $_SESSION['userSession'] = false;
    }

}
```

```
<?php
class Database
{

    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "dslr_proj";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "";
    public $conn;

    public function dbConnection()
    {

        $this->conn = null;    
        try
        {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
        }
        catch(PDOException $exception)
        {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you show what code you have at the moment?

Comment: What exact row do you want to display for the user?

Comment: i want to display previously uploaded data of that particular user..

Comment: Where in the database is that?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, after your login function returns true, you redirect to the profile page. You can use your session to get data from database. Can you show the script of the page after login?

Comment: I have two tables in database. How to retrieve  data from cam_info table of particular user who previously uploaded data into dat table

Comment: SELECT cd.user_id, cd.user_name, cd.mobile, cd.cam_name, cd.rent, cd.model, cd.cam_img, cd.upd_date, ru.* FROM cam_details cd LEFT JOIN reg_users ru ON ru.userID = cd.user_id WHERE ru.userID = :id